# Как проверить, доступен раздел или нет?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Как можно ограничить доступ к пункту меню?

Есть таблица с доступами, ее структура:

```
id
id_staff
id_cabinet (id кабинета в который может заходить сотрудник)
vid_access (вид доступа, например: **access_balance**)
access (если 0 то запрещен доступ, если 1 то разрешен)
```

Как, допустим, ограничить доступ к разделу меню с названием balance?

**Как сделать?**

Comment: id_staff - ид пользователя?

Comment: Да, это id сотрудника, к которому относятся настройки доступа.

Comment: У меня много пунктов и разделов, хотелось бы какое-нибудь недлинное решение, но додумать не могу, как сделать...

Comment: Тогда при загрузке нужного раздела вам надо обратится в базу, передав id пользователя и название меню, посмотреть, разрешен доступ или нет, и выдать нужное сообщение или показать меню. Все можно оформить в функцию, например, `access(id_staff, id_menu)`.

Comment: Ну, я, собственно, так и делаю, извлекаю в самом начале страницы по id сотрудника базу доступов, а если у меня, допустим, вот так сделано: 

    <? if ($myrow_cabinet['id_admin'] == $userdata['id_staff']) { ?><li class="fdi_cr calendar"><a href="/calendar/"><div class="menu-icon calendar_i"></div><div class="title-menu">Календарь</div></a></li><? }  ?>

    <? if ($myrow_cabinet['id_admin'] == $userdata['id_staff']) { ?><li class="fdi_cr conversion"><a href="/statistics/lids"><div class="menu-icon conversion_i"></div><div class="title-menu">Аналитика</div></a></li><?  } ?>

Как тут поступить?

Comment: Не совсем вас понял. Что вам именно нужно?

Comment: Как мне ограничить, допустим, доступ к разделу меню "аналитика"? 

Вот такой же вариант неправильный: 

    <? if ($myrow_access['vid_access'] == 'access_settings') { if ($myrow_access['access'] == '1') { ?><li class="fdi_cr conversion"><a href="/statistics/lids"><div class="menu-icon conversion_i"></div><div class="title-menu">Аналитика</div></a></li><? } } ?>

Comment: Напишите запрос

    "select access from 'table' where id_statt='id-пользователя' and id_cabinet='id-кабинета' and vid_access='access_settings'".

Вы получите значение access, например, в переменную $access.  
И тогда

    <? if ($access==1) { ?><li class="fdi_cr conversion"><a href="/statistics/lids"><div class="menu-icon conversion_i"></div><div class="title-menu">Аналитика</div></a></li><? } ?>

Comment: Возможно ли сделать то, что я хочу, классом? 

    function access($vid_access) {
       $query_access = mysql_query("SELECT access FROM access_staff WHERE id_staff = '".$userdata['id_staff']."' and id_cabinet = '".$myrow_cabinet['id']."' and vid_access = '".$vid_access."'");
       $myrow_access = mysql_fetch_array($query_access);
       $access = $myrow_access['access'];
       echo $access;
    }


и, допустим, потом где-то вызывать 

    if (access ('access_settings') == '1') { ... }

Comment: Что-то я не понял - а почему сразу запросом не пройтись и не получить только то, куда доступ разрешен?

    select access from 'table' where id_statt=ЮЗЕР and access=1

и потом не городить

    if (access ('access_settings') == '1')

Comment: Потому что у меня есть места, где без if не обойтись. Например, закрыть доступ к определенной кнопке или пункту меню.

Comment: Так и выводи на основе того, что уже  разрешено точно, но без проверок. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и выводи на основе того, что уже  разрешено точно, но без проверок if.  )
Я так понимаю, меню выводим - так и храни в Базе пути пунктов меню.
Что-то типа того:

```
id
id_staff
id_cabinet (id кабинета в который может заходить сотрудник)
vid_access (вид доступа, например: **access_balance**)
access (если 0 то запрещен доступ, если 1 то разрешен)
name (наименование пункта)
url (адрес ссылки)
```

Делаем запрос

```
select access from 'table' where id_statt=ЮЗЕР and access=1
```

Потом обрабатываем

```
$strmenu='';
foreach ($resultas as  $value) 
{
$strmenu.='<li class="класс тоже можно в базу пихнуть"><a href="'.$value['url'].'"><div class="класс тоже можно в базу пихнуть"></div><div class="класс тоже можно в базу пихнуть">'.$value['name'].'</div></a></li>';           
}
```

Класс тоже можно в базу пихнуть - если разные для разных пунктов, если одинаковые, то просто их и пишите.

Comment: Хорошее решение, но я сделал лучше. Через функцию.